# Kafka Streams KTable configuration error on Message Hub

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, message-hub

**This issue is now solved on Message Hub**

I am having some trouble creating a KTable in Kafka. I am new to Kafka, which is probably the root of my problem, but I thought I could ask here anyway. I have a project where I would like to keep track of different IDs by counting their total occurrence. I am using [Message Hub](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/message-hub) on IBM Cloud to manage my topics, and it has worked splendid so far.

I have a topic on Message Hub that produces messages like `{"ID":"123","TIMESTAMP":"1525339553", "BALANCE":"100", "AMOUNT":"4"}`, for now, the only key of relevance is ID.

My Kafka code, along with the Streams configuration, looks like this:

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, appId);
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
props.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, "3");    
props.put("security.protocol","SASL_SSL");
props.put("sasl.mechanism","PLAIN");
props.put("ssl.protocol","TLSv1.2");
props.put("ssl.enabled.protocols","TLSv1.2");
String saslJaasConfig = "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"USERNAME\" password=\"PASSWORD\";";
saslJaasConfig = saslJaasConfig.replace("USERNAME", user).replace("PASSWORD", password);
props.put("sasl.jaas.config",saslJaasConfig);

StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

KStream<String, String> Kstreams = builder.stream(myTopic);

KTable<String, Long> eventCount = Kstreams
        .flatMapValues(value -> getID(value)) //function that retrieves the ID
        .groupBy((key, value) -> value)
        .count();
```

When I run the code, I get the following error(s):

> Exception in thread "KTableTest-e2062d11-0b30-4ed0-82b0-00d83dcd9366->StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Could not create topic KTableTest-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition.

Followed by:

> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PolicyViolationException: Invalid configuration: {segment.index.bytes=52428800, segment.bytes=52428800, cleanup.policy=delete, segment.ms=600000}. Only allowed configs: [retention.ms, cleanup.policy]

I have no idea why this error occurs, and what could be done about it. Is the way I have built the KStream and KTable incorrect somehow? Or perhaps the message hub on bluemix?

**Solved:**

Adding an extract from the comments below the answer I have marked as correct. Turned out my StreamsConfig was fine, and that there (for now) is an issue on Message Hub's side, but there is a workaround:

*It turns out Message Hub has an issue when creating repartition topics with Kafka Streams 1.1. While we work on a fix, you'll need to create the topic KTableTest-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition by hand. It needs as many partitions as your input topic (myTopic) and set the retention time to the max. I'll post another comment once it's fixed*

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you add your Kafka Streams application configuration (or properties file) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Message Hub has some [restrictions](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/messagehub108.html#topic_admin) on the configurations that can be used when creating topics.

From the PolicyViolationException you received, it looks like your Streams application tried to use a few configs we don't allow:

- segment.index.bytes
- segment.bytes
- segment.ms

I'm guessing you set those somewhere in your Streams configuration and they should be removed.

Note that you also need to set `StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG` to 3 in your config to work with Message Hub as mentioned in our [docs](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/messagehub111.html#kafka_streams).

Comment: Thank you for replying! I think you are definitely right. I added my streams configuration, but I think the necessities in order to make it work with Message Hub(MH) is already in place. At least according to the docs. What I do not understand is why I get "Could not create topic", when I am not trying to, unless a KTable counts as one? Could it be solved by allocating a topic on the MH? Like I wrote in the start of my question, I would like to count the occurrence of the IDs in the topic from MH, does it have to do more with MH than simply listen to the topic?

Comment: Yes your transformation logic will create "internal" topics, see http://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/developer-guide/manage-topics.html#streams-developer-guide-topics-internal. You could pre-create them by hand beforehand but it's usually easier to let Streams do it.
Otherwise, I think your logic looks fine.

Comment: I see. So when I try to create a KTable, that is when I get the error since I am restricted from creating a topic in this way on Message Hub. Have I understood right if the code I have is retrieving the messages from a MH topic and try to create an internal topic(KTable) on MH? Is there a way alter my code to create the KTable elsewhere with Streams? Or do I need another Kafka server in order to achieve what I am after? Can MH handle KTables? Sorry for all the questions, I am really appreciating your help.

Comment: I managed to reproduce your issue. It turns out Message Hub has an issue when creating repartition topics with Kafka Streams 1.1. While we work on a fix, you'll need to create the topic `KTableTest-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition` by hand. It needs as many partitions as your input topic (myTopic) and set the retention time to the max. I'll post another comment once it's fixed

Comment: I completely forgot to post here, but this issue has been fixed a few weeks ago